# Data analysis libraries for Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

Is there any GAS libraries for data analysis and matrix operations? Something like Python `numpy` & `pandas` or JavaScript `numjs` &`undescorejs`. I want to do some statistical operations in GAS.

Comment: There's no popular GAS library for data analysis. Any library with Javascript 1.6 support will work with GAS. If it does not, you must transpile the library to es3. Search for transpilers/shims.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider **d3.js**

```
  var d3Url = "https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(d3Url).getContentText());
  var array = [4,5,5,9];
  Logger.log(d3.max(array));
  Logger.log(d3.mean(array));
  Logger.log(d3.median(array));
  Logger.log(d3.sum(array));
```

More detail [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#statistics).